# HALOT BOX makes objects with support move up

Tags: slicing, resin, creality

I'm trying to slice some models using the default HALOT BOX software from Creality, which comes with the [Halot One](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/products/halot-one-cl-60-resin-3d-printer) resin 3D printer.

I've oriented them at 45 degrees, and am using supports.  When I come to slice the models, the models all jump up a few millimetres, as seen in the below screenshot.

I thought it was just a UI bug, until the same image also appears on the printer screen, with a gap between the supports and the raft.

[image: Floating models]

If I reset the position of the model, it goes back down as I would expect it to be, but when I click "slice" it moves back up again.

[image: One object back in place]

My settings are as follows:

[image: Slicer settings]

How do I fix this?

Comment: height from Raft

Comment: @Trish Just tried messing around with that, and it appears that defines how far up the model is moved before the supports are created. You can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2t7j.png) that it's touching the bottom, and the "Generate support" button is actually disabled (hard to see, but it is). When put it back to 6mm, it can generate supports and [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JL8q.png) before trying to slice (after which it jumps up again as per the question).

Comment: Have you tried "height from Raft 0.2" for a very tiny gap?

Comment: @Trish the lowest it lets me go is 2mm.  I tried that, but it still jumps up, so I tried setting the raft height higher but it still jumps up beyond that as well.  Maybe I need to file a bug report with the developers, but it's a bit annoying I can only use the HALOT BOX software and not something of my choice :(

Comment: @Trish So I did what I should have done at the start, and checked for an updated version of the software, which now appears to work!  Annoyingly when I ran "Check for updates" within the software it said I was using the latest version, but there was actually a newer version on the Creality website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was using an old (and buggy) version of the software.

The version I was using came on the supplied USB memory stick and was version 1.9-something.

I downloaded the latest version (2.0-something) off [the Creality website](https://www.creality.com/download) and now it doesn't appear to have the same problem.

[image: Yay!]

Comment: Thank you for providing this info! I too, have had so many failures because the slicer would raise the supports off of the raft. And you can't tell if its printing anything until a couple hours into the print when it rises out of the resin enough to see if anything is there. So much wasted time on version 1.9!!!